# Wordpress, form caching and show hide div

Tags: javascript, wordpress

In my Wordpress (3.8.1) i have made a form. I have 1 checkbox when i click on it a hidden div shows on the screen asking to input extra information.

Javascript code for showing the hidden div:

```
$(function(){
   $('.toggler').click(function(){
       if (this.checked) {
           $('div.showdiv').slideDown();
       } else {
           $('div.showdiv').slideUp();
       }
   });
})
```

When i fill in the form and accidentally refresh the page then the browser remind the options i have checked and text i have putted, except my hidden div is hidden again even if the check box is still checked. So i have to uncheck and check again and there is the hidden div again. It is not so important and maybe it will never happen someone refreshes the page but you never know.

I am not so good in Javascript hope someone could help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if/else function is called only when you click on the checkbox. So when the page is refreshed, there is no click on the checkbox and so no display/hide of the div.

You can do this to check the status of the checkbox when the page is displayed :

```
$(function(){
  // Check the checkbox status when the page is displayed
  if ($('.toggler').is(":checked")){
    $('div.showdiv').slideDown();
  } else {
    $('div.showdiv').slideUp();
  }

  // And change the status on click
  $('.toggler').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
      $('div.showdiv').slideDown();
    } else {
      $('div.showdiv').slideUp();
    }
  });
})
```